# Integral Calculus - can someone help with this question

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

The coroner arrived at exactly 10 p.m. and found the temperature of Mr. Body's body to be 28∘ C. The temperature of the water surrounding the body was 17∘ C and remained constant throughout the day and evening. Let T represent the temperature of the body in degrees Celsius and t represent time in hours since the murder occurred.

According to Newton's Law of Heating and Cooling,
dTdt=k(T−17)
for some constant k.

(a) Use Separation of Variables to find an expression for T in terms of t, measured since the time of death, assuming that Mr. Body's temperature was exactly 37∘ at the time of his death. Your answer may include the constant k. Be sure to show your work rather than using a memorized formula.

(b)  By 11 pm (1 hour after the coroner arrived), the temperature of the body dropped to 26.11∘ C. Find an expression involving natural logarithms that, when evaluated, will give A, the time between the victim's death and the time the coroner arrived.

Comment: Did you manage to solve part (a)?

Comment: Yes I did!!!!!!

Comment: Good, so what about part (b)? What was the difficulty you encountered?

Comment: Everything. How do I go about it? Could you work it out a little for me?

Comment: What expression did you get for part (a)?  You will need to use that expression to solve part (b).

Comment: The expression you got from part (a) probably has an unknown constant. However, use the expression in part (b) and you'll be able to figure out the value of the constant. Then you will be able to solve the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the part a) you need to get the formula you use in part b)

a) $dT dt=k(T-17)\\
\frac{1}{dt}=\frac{dT}{k(T-17)}$

Then integrate both sides

$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\frac{1}{dt}=\int_{T_0}^{T_1}\frac{dT}{k(T-17)}\\
log(t_1)-log(t_0)=\frac{log(T_1-17)}{k}-\frac{log(T_0-17)}{k}$

b) Now to solve you first need to find k. Since one hour passes you can assume $t_0=1$ and $t_1=2$ whereas $T_0=28$ and $T_1=26.11$

$k=\frac{log(28-17)-log(26.11-17)}{log(t_1)-log(t_0)}\\
k=0.2719$

To find out when the fictim died you can use the initial formula again but with $T_0=37$ and $T_1=28$ as:

$\frac{log(28-17)}{k}-\frac{log(37-17)}{k}=2.198$

Using exponent

$log(\frac{t_1}{t_0})=2.198\\
\frac{t_1}{t_0}=9$

9 hours have passed since the victim died